# Jquery Horizontal Accordion Webkit Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, accordion

I'm trying to build a horizontal accordion with Jquery.  It seems to be working "ok" in Firefox.  But in Webkit (Safari 3 + 4, and Chrome) the sub-level UL flashes after the Hide function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. To see a working demo: http://ableobject.com/horaccordion1.html

Here is what I'm working on:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container {
        display: table; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        text-align: center; /* for IE */
    }
            ul{
                    list-style: none;
                    background-color: yellow;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    float: left;
                    height: 20px; /* For testing */     
            }
            ul li {
                   background-color: aqua;
                    float: left;
            }
            ul li ul {
                   background-color: blue;
                    display: none;
            }
            ul li ul li {
                   background-color: green;
            }
            a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
                    color: black;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    float: left;
            }
    </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">
/* Care of Hunter Daley */
    var $current = null;
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("ul li ul").hide();  // hide submenus by default on load

           $("ul li a").click(function(){
              var $sub = $(this).next(); 
              if ($sub.css("display") == "none")
              {
                 if ($current != null)
                    $current.animate({ width: 'hide' }); // if you want to only show one sub at a time
                 $sub.animate({ width: 'show' }); 
                 $current = $sub;
              }
              else
              {
                 $sub.animate({ width: 'hide' });
                 $current = null;
              }
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    <ul>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 2</a>

                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A4</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 3</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B2</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <a href="#">Top-level 4</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it is related to an issue I had a little while ago with webkit. There is a webkit bug that sometimes causes an element's parent to revert to its original size after an animation that reduces the elements' width. After the animation, the element's parent jumps back to its original size in order to accommodate its content.

**Edit: Removed comments about jQueryUI. Not sure why I thought you were using it.**

The bug was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920718/jquery-div-pops-back-to-full-size-after-animation), which details a workaround.

I submitted a [bug report](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4692) to jQuery as well.

Basically, you would need to  simultaneously reduce the width of your `$sub` element's parent by the same amount as `$sub` is being reduced. So if the width of `$sub` is 100px, there would be a separate `animate()` to reduce the parent by 100px.

I haven't tested any of this with your example, but I think it is probably the key.

**Edit 2:**
A new version using divs

**CSS:**

```
.title {
       list-style: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       float: left;
       height: 32px; /* For testing */
       font-family: helvetica;
       font-size: 18px;
       clip: auto; overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
       height: 32px; /* For testing */
       clip: auto; overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
}
a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
       color: black;
       text-decoration: none;
       padding: 12px;
       font-weight: 700;
       float: left;
       color: #222;
}

 .menu a, .menu a:link, .menu a:hover, .menu a:visited, .menu a:active {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 12px;
   font-weight: normal;
   float: left;
```

}

**javascript:**

```
    // Prevents us from having to check for null.
    var $current = $('#someFictionalElement');
    var $previous = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").css({width: 0});  // hide submenus by default on load

    $(".title").click(
        function() {
            $previous = $current;
            $current = $(this);
            var $currentMenu = $current.next();

            $previous.next().animate({ width: 0 }, {duration: 1000, queue: false} );

    // Make sure that if there's no menu text (like Top Level 1 and 4) that it does not animate.
    // This is because of the pixels added for Firefox (see comment below)
            if( $currentMenu.width() == 0 && $currentMenu.text() != ''  ) {

    // Expand the menu but keep it hidden so we can get its width
                $currentMenu.css({visibility: 'hidden', width: ''});

    // Store the width, and add a few pixels for Firefox
                var currentWidth = $currentMenu.width() + 3;

    // Make menu visible and set with to 0 in preparation for the animation
                $currentMenu.css({visibility: 'visible', width: 0})
                            .animate({ width: currentWidth }, 1000);
            }
    });

    $(".title a").hover(
        function(){$(this).animate ({ opacity: 0.7 }, 200);},
        function(){$(this).animate ({ opacity: 1 }, 600);}
    );
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class='title' id='level1'>
            <a href="#">Top-level 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menu'></div>
        <div class='title' id='level2'>
            <a href="#">Top-level 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menu'>                         
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A1</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A2</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A3</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A4</a>
        </div>
        <div class='title' id='level3'>
            <a href="#">Top-level 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class='menu'>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level B1</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level B2</a>
        </div>
        <div class='title' id='level4'>
            <a href="#">Top-level 4</a>
        </div>      
        <div class='menu'></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried it out http://ableobject.com/horaccordion2.html but when I'm going from Toplevel 4 from an expanded Toplevel 3 it still flashes.  I'll try to figure it out and repost... but at the moment the solution escapes me.  
Maybe:

  $sub.parent().css({ width: '' });
             $current = $sub;

?

Comment: How important is the use of 'list' elements to you? After finally ditching them and using div's, I came up with a fairly concise accordion that works in webkit.

Comment: Its not all that important, I just didn't want to define widths for the list items (or, divs).

Comment: No need to set widths on divs when you float left. Not sure if this is the best way, but you don't have the webkit flashing problem anyway. It's the cleanest and most concise way I could find. Only weird thing was a Firefox fix that was needed (see code comments). Hope its helpful.

Comment: great, thanks patrick. There seems to be another issue with webkit about center-aligning the menu.  
It works in Firefox by using 
display: table; 
margin: 0 auto;
and ie IE using
text-align: center;
on #container
but webkit won't doesn't work!
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes, I see. Looks like webkit is actually centering it, but the width #container is still expanded as though all the menu items are shown. If you give the #container a background color, and make your browser window wide enough, you'll see that it is actually centered. (If your screen isn't big enough, you would need to delete some menu items to see the effect.) I'll play around some more and see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a separate answer just in case you still find the previous one useful.

Please note the following:

- I have not tested this in ie.
- This goes back to a 'nested' version, so I changed the class and variable names a little.
- An empty menu is no longer needed when there is no menu to display.
- The width of each menu's 'container' is now being reduced the same amount as the menu. This is what eliminates webkit's temporary flash (which was the original strategy).
- You'll notice the the timing of the animation of the menu is slightly different than that of the menu's container. Basically, you want the container to be a little ahead when expanding, and the menu to be a little ahead when reducing. If the timing is set to be equal, you can get some flashing of the menu.
- As explained in the comments, at the beginning, each menu 'memorizes' its width when fully expanded by setting a previously non-existent attribute called 'fullWidth'. It then retrieves the value of this attribute when needed. You could just as easily use global variables, or jQuery's data() function to store the info. The point is that things are simplified if each menu is aware of how wide it should be when it is expanded.

So here it is. Hope it helps!

**CSS**

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

.menuContainer {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       float: left;
       height: 32px; /* For testing */
       font-family: helvetica;
       font-size: 18px;
       clip: auto; overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
       height: 32px; /* For testing */
       clip: auto; overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
}
a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
       color: black;
       text-decoration: none;
       padding: 12px;
       font-weight: 700;
       float: left;
       color: #222;
}

.menu a, .menu a:link, .menu a:hover, .menu a:visited, .menu a:active {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 12px;
   font-weight: normal;
   float: left;
}
```

**javascript**

```
var $currentMenuContainer = $('#someFictionalElement');
var $previousMenuContainer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

// Iterate through each .menu element, setting the full width of each menu to a 'custom'
//        attribute called 'fullWidth'. Since the full width should never change, this
//        makes it easy to recall it quickly. You could use global variables instead.
// After setting 'fullWidth', it then collapses each menu and title.
$(".menu").each(function() {
    var $theMenu = $(this);
    var $theMenuContainer = $theMenu.parent();
    $theMenu.attr({fullWidth: ($theMenu.width() + 3)});   // Add a few pixels for firefox
    var menuContainerWidth = $theMenuContainer.width() - $theMenu.attr('fullWidth') + 6;  // Add DOUBLE the pixels here
    $theMenu.css({width: 0});
    $theMenuContainer.css({width: menuContainerWidth});
});

    $(".menuContainer a").click(
        function() {
// Set the current and previous elements properly
            $previousMenuContainer = $currentMenuContainer;
            $currentMenuContainer = $(this).parent();
            var $previousMenu = $previousMenuContainer.find('.menu');
            var $currentMenu = $currentMenuContainer.find('.menu');

// Collapse the previous menu
            $previousMenu.animate({ width: 0 }, {duration: 480, queue: false} );

// Subtract the width of the previous menuContainer's menu from the menuContainer (only if its menu is displayed)
            if($previousMenu.width() > 0) $previousMenuContainer.animate({width: ('-=' + $previousMenu.attr('fullWidth'))}, 500);

// Expand the current menu and its menuContainer if it's not showing
            if($currentMenu.width() == 0) {
                // Increase the menuContainer width by the full width of its menu
                $currentMenuContainer.animate({width: ('+=' + $currentMenu.attr('fullWidth'))}, 480);
                // Increase the menuContainer to its full width
                $currentMenu.animate({ width: $currentMenu.attr('fullWidth') }, 500);
            }
    });

    $(".menuContainer a").hover(
        function(){$(this).animate ({ opacity: 0.7 }, 200);},
        function(){$(this).animate ({ opacity: 1 }, 600);}
    );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class='menuContainer'>
        <a href="#">Top-level 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menuContainer'>
        <a href="#">Top-level 2</a>
        <div class='menu'>                         
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A1</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A2</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A3</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level A4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='menuContainer'>
        <a href="#">Top-level 3</a>
        <div class='menu'>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level B1</a>
            <a href="#">Bottom Level B2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='menuContainer'>
        <a href="#">Top-level 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Add the following DTD to the top of your page-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: This works great, now if i can only figure out how to center it in IE :)

Comment: I'm encountering a strange bug in Firefox... I've changed the link size to 16px, and now the Bottom Level A4 disappears?  I've tried adding more (and less) pixels... and playing with the padding... I can't seem to get it to show up

Comment: For ie to center, add the following to the very top of the page. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
I think I should be able to figure out the Firefox issue. Will probably get back to you on Monday.

Comment: OK, I actually got it pretty quick. I've corrected the .each() method in the javascript. How ever many pixels are added to the menu, twice as many need to be added to the menu's container.

Comment: Everything is working well, I'm converting it to work with Ems as well.  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> doesn't seem to center it, neither does containing it with <center></center>.  I've put a test up at http://ableobject.com/horaccordion.html